# Debug Log Traced Entity Type Apex Class

Tags: apex, debugging, debug, debug-logs

I am setting the `debug log` Entity Type to APEX `Class` and it is not logging anything when I call the class.

The class I am setting it as is definitely being called, the date/time is set to 24 hours from now, and the debug log type is Default.

Am I missing something? I call the class by updating a field value on the Opportunity object. There is a webservice involved and no visualforce pages.

Comment: Are you using debug logs in set-up or the developer console?

Comment: in set up, should I be using dev console?

Comment: No, I just wanted to make sure before I posted an answer but it looks like SFDCFox already beat me to it :) If you were doing it in the dev console, it wouldn't have been what SFDCFox's answer suggests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to also set a TraceFlag on the user you want to trace. A TraceFlag set on a class only overrides the TraceFlag settings for the user; you use them together to get detailed analysis on a specific class without flooding the log with details from classes you're not interested in.